# body_filter_by_lua_block nginx lua

Tags: nginx, lua

The code below is Nginx Lua:

```
body_filter_by_lua_block {
    function check_access_file(file)
        local fh = io.open(file,'rb')
        if fh then
            fh:close()
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
        return false
    end  

    function write_file(file, str)
        local check_access_file = check_access_file(file)
        if check_access_file  then
            local fh = io.open(file, "a")
            fh:write(str, "\n")
            fh:close()
        end
    end
    write_file('/etc/nginx/111', '1234567='..ngx.arg[1])
}
```

When you run it once, 2 replies are written to the file

```
1234567 = test
1234567 =
```

Why with each request two responses are written to file 111?

Comment: Show full nginx config.

Comment: add full nginx config